# How define url params inside state common for each child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

This is my config:

```
     .state('index.oz', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/oz',
        views: {
            'mainView@': {
                templateUrl: "Views/oz/oz.html",
                controller: 'ozController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.iz.a', {
        url: '/a/:id',
        params: {
            id: {
                value: null,
                squash:true
            }
        },
        views: {
            'ozTypeView': {
                templateUrl: "Views/oz/a.html",
                controller: "ozaController"
            }
        }
    })
    .state('index.oz.b', {
        url: '/b/:id',
        params: {
            id: {
                value: null,
                squash:true
            }
        },
        views: {
            'ozTypeView': {
                templateUrl: "Views/oz/ozb.html",
                controller: 'ozbController'
            }
        }
    });
```

My desired urls are:

/oz/a

/oz/b

/oz/a/45

/oz/b/12

How can I make url in each child state so that I don't have to in each state write following piece fo code:

```
       params: {
            id: {
                value: null,
                squash:true
            }
        }
```

More spedific, can I somehow put that piece of code inside parent abstract state, or maybe even define parameter id inside parent state, but keeping my desired urls as mentioned above? Basicly, I'll have couple child states and I don't want for each state repeat same params code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess directly you cant, but you can reduce code duplication like this:

```
function stateWithId(name, cfg) {
  cfg.url += '/:id';
  if (!cfg.params) {
    cfg.params = {};
  }
  cfg.params.id = {
                value: null,
                squash:true
  };
  $stateProvider.state(name, cfg);
}

stateWithId('index.iz.a', {
        url: '/a',
        views: {
            'ozTypeView': {
                templateUrl: "Views/oz/a.html",
                controller: "ozaController"
            }
        }
    });
stateWithId('index.iz.b', {
        url: '/b'
});
```